# Encoding string issue reading a CSV file in C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, encoding, character-encoding, windows-phone

I am currently developing a Windows Phone 8 application in which one I have to download a CSV file from a web-service and convert data to a C# business object (I do not use a library for this part).

Download the file and convert data to a C# business object is not an issue using RestSharp.Portable, `StreamReader` class and `MemoryStream` class.

The issue I face to is about the bad encoding of the string fields.

With the library RestSharp.Portable, I retrieve the csv file content as a byte array and then convert data to string with the following code (where `response` is a byte array) :

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(response)))
{
  while (streamReader.Peek() >= 0)
  {
    var csvLine = streamReader.ReadLine();
  }
}
```

but instead of "Jérome", my `csvLine` variable contains `J�rome`. I tried several things to obtain `Jérome` but without success like :

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(response), true))
```

or

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(response), Encoding.UTF8))
```

When I open the CSV file with a simple notepad software like notepad++ I obtain `Jérome` only when the file is encoding in ANSI. But if I try the following code in C# :

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(response), Encoding.GetEncoding("ANSI")))
```

I have the following exception :

> 'ANSI' is not a supported encoding name.

Can someone help me to decode correctly my CSV file ?

Thank you in advance for your help or advices !

Comment: First convert your file to UTF-8, then use that encoding

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Help reading foreign characters using StreamReader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592824/c-sharp-help-reading-foreign-characters-using-streamreader)

Comment: For `GetEncoding(string)` the argument must be a so-called [WebName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.webname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), i.e. an IANA-registered encoding name such as `Windows-1252`.

Comment: @AlexanderObersht @archon @Amit : thx for your help. I finally found a working solution using `using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(response), Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pick one of these.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx

If you don't know, you can try to guess it.  Guessing isn't a perfect solution, per the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90838/how-can-i-detect-the-encoding-codepage-of-a-text-file).

> You can't detect the codepage, you need to be told it. You can analyse the bytes and guess it, but that can give some bizarre (sometimes amusing) results.

Comment: Thx for your answer. Unfortunately teh following code `new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(response), Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252")` gives me the error : 'Windows-1252' is not a supported encoding name. :(

Comment: Finally, investigating from your link, I found the following thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14110730/reading-windows-1252-encoding-in-windows-phone-8 with the following answer that works for me : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14110867/2762990 ! I am going to post the solution as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

From the link of Lawtonfogle I tried to use

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(response), Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252")))
```

But I had the following error :

> 'Windows-1252' is not a supported encoding name.

Searching why on the internet, I finally found following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14110730/reading-windows-1252-encoding-in-windows-phone-8) with the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14110730/reading-windows-1252-encoding-in-windows-phone-8/14110867#14110867) that works for me.

So here the working solution in my case :

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(response), Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")))
{
  while (streamReader.Peek() >= 0)
  {
    var csvLine = streamReader.ReadLine();
  }
}
```