# I get this Error if i try to SELECT some data: 'windows-1252' is not a supported encoding name

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm trying to build a Windows Universal App with a MySql database. My problem is, that when i try to do a SELECT command, I get this error:
**'windows-1252' is not a supported encoding name.'**

**I'm usining MySQL Connector Net 6.9.8 and Visual Studio 2015.**

There is a realted post wich has exactly the same problems like me:
[Windows -1252 is not supported encoding name. C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32471058/windows-1252-is-not-supported-encoding-name-c-sharp)

But I'm a beginner with universal apps. During my resarch I also found this post: [Reading Windows-1252 encoding in Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14110730/reading-windows-1252-encoding-in-windows-phone-8), in the first command, there is al link to a manual encoder.
But as I told you I am a beginner and so I didn't get the solution and also have no idea how to use this for my app.
Please explain for an beginner ;)

EDIT:
At first I got the same porblem with the INSERT command, but I could fix it with setting `charset=utf8` in the connection. But this doesn't work with the SELECT command.

Here is the cod of my App:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using SQLite;
using MySql;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }


    #region ++++++++MySql++++++++
    static string server = "127.0.0.1";
    static string database = "test";
    static string user = "root";
    static string pswd = "";
    MySqlConnection connectionMySql;
    int id = 1;

    private void MySqlConnectButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlStatusTextBlock.Text = "Connecting...";
        string connectionString = "Server = " + server + ";database = " + database + ";uid = " + user + ";password = " + pswd + ";SslMode=None;charset=utf8";
        connectionMySql = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        connectionMySql.Open();
        MySqlStatusTextBlock.Text = "Connected";
    }

    private void MySqlAddButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Foods food = new Foods() { Name = MySqlElementA.Text, Keyword = MySqlElementB.Text, Calories = int.Parse(MySqlElementC.Text), Fat = double.Parse(MySqlElementD.Text), Carbs = 33.4, Protein = 24.8 };

        string para = "('" + id + "','" + food.Name + "','" + food.Keyword + "','" + food.Calories + "','" + food.Fat + "','" + food.Carbs + "', '" + food.Protein + "') ";
        string commandMySql = "INSERT INTO `foods`(`id`, `name`, `keyword`, `calories`, `fat`, `carbs`, `protein`) VALUES" + para;
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(commandMySql, connectionMySql);

        MySqlDataReader dr;
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        int count = 0;
        while (dr.Read())
            count += 1;
        if (count == 0)
        {
            MySqlStatusTextBlock.Text = "Added";
        }
        else
        {
            MySqlStatusTextBlock.Text = "Error";
        }
        dr.Close();

    }

    private void MySqlShowAllButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
        List<Foods> f_list = new List<Foods>();
        string query = "SELECT * FROM `foods` WHERE 1 ";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connectionMySql);

        MySqlDataReader dr;
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); **<--- Here occurs the error**

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            Foods f_get = new Foods() {ID = dr.GetInt32("id"), Name = dr.GetString("name"), Keyword =dr.GetString("keyword"), Calories = dr.GetInt32("calories"), Fat = dr.GetDouble("fat"), Carbs = dr.GetDouble("cabrs"), Protein = dr.GetDouble("protein")};
            f_list.Add(f_get);
        }
        string textbox = String.Empty;
        foreach(Foods f in f_list)
        {
            textbox = String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}", f.ID.ToString(), f.Name, f.Keyword, f.Calories, f.Fat, f.Carbs, f.Protein) + System.Environment.NewLine;
        }
        MySqlResultTextBlock.Text = textbox;

    }
    #endregion


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't worked with only setting the collation to utf8,

```
ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

but in in your link [Collation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-applications.html) the first command get it work.
**So thank you very much!** Here is how i get it fixed:

> If you use PHP with mysql you may want to use
>   in **my.ini:**
>   skip-character-set-client-handshake
>   with:

```
collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
character_set_server=utf8
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make changes in database, not on the client side.
Check your database [collation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-applications.html)
You can try convert database and table collaction with:

```
ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

PS: don't forget to make a backup before conversion.